# how to removes '-' in dates with a df column of dates

Tags: pandas, datetime

I want to add 3 columns together. column 1 and 2 have dates in the format of "%Y-%m-%d" but i want to change the format to "%Y%m%d" for each date in both columns and then add it to a third column of strings. I have tried the below code.

```
df['code'] = df['date_one'].strftime("%Y%m%d") + df['date_two'].strftime("%Y%m%d") + df['id'].astype(str)
```

But i keep getting an error saying series object has no strftime, can someone please help me?

Comment: tried `df[...].dt.strftime("%Y%m%d")`? for datetime series, you need to use the accessor object `dt()`.

Comment: i get this error using the above AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: Seems like you need to convert the column to datetime first, see NYCCoder's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `pd.to_datetime` for this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')

       Date
0  20120507
1  20120507
2  20120507
3  20120507
```